# How do I bind 2 Lists in ItemsControl in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am implementing a vertical menu with one Sub Menus using Radio Buttons and ListBox. The Model is like,

```
public class MainMenuItem
    {
        public int MenuID { get; set; }
        public string MenuName { get; set; }            
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        public List<SubMenuItem> SubMenuList { get; set; } 
    }

    public class SubMenuItem
    {
        public int MenuID { get; set; }
        public string SubMenuName { get; set; }            
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
    }
```

In the xaml,

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuList}">
    
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <RadioButton x:Name="MainMenu"                                 
                             GroupName="MainMenu"
                             Content="{Binding MenuName}"
                             Height="30"/>
                <ListBox
                    ItemsSource="{Binding SubMenuList}"                         
                    />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

So far it's working fine. Now I want to add Sub Sub Menu Under SubMenuItem like,

```
public class SubMenuItem
{
    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    public string SubMenuName { get; set; }            
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public List<SubSubMenuItem> SubSubMenuList { get; set; }
}
public class SubSubMenuItem
{
    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    public string SubSubMenuName { get; set; }            
    public int ParentID { get; set; }        
}
```

ViewModel is accurately populating the Menu List with SubMenuList and SubSubMenuList. How to Implement this in xaml in my existing menu Items Control?

Comment: And after that SubSubSubMenuItem? Why aren't you using [WPF menus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/menu-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)? Anyway, you won't have to use different classes for the different levels. A `MenuItem` class can have a `List<MenuItem>` member. You would thus be able to create a recursive structure with as many levels as you like. Then you would extract the DataTemplate as a XAML resource and set its DataType property. It would automatically be selected for all levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily make a menu vertical by using a stackpanel as itemspanel.

And re-template a menuitem to your preference.

I've not done that last part but here's what a simple mvvm style menu might look like:

Mainwindow markup.

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <Menu.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Header}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
                </Style>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                     DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildMenuItems}">
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </Menu.Resources>
            <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemsPanel>
        </Menu>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}"
                        Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public List<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>
        {
            new MenuItemViewModel
            { Header="AAA",
             ChildMenuItems=new List<MenuItemViewModel>
             {
                  new MenuItemViewModel {Header="AAA Child 1" },
                  new MenuItemViewModel {Header="AAA Child 2" }
             }
            },
            new MenuItemViewModel
            { Header="BBB" }
        };
    }
}
```

I've (obviously) not set up any commands there.

Menu item viewmodel:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand Command { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItemViewModel> ChildMenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

If your menu structure is dynamic you could use observablecollection rather than list and you could make commands dynamic by raising propertychanged when set.